# How to calculate output length for PHP Mcrypt Rijndael 256 CBC

Tags: php, cakephp, mcrypt, rijndael, cbc-mode

I want to use a plug-in for cakephp to store encrypted data in the database. But I want to calculate how much length is necessary for database fields.

Here is the encryption code of the plugin:

```
return base64_encode(
     mcrypt_encrypt(
          MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5($settings['key']
     ), $value, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5(md5($settings['key']
))));
```

For instance how much field length is necessary for 2000 lengthed raw string input? VARCHAR(?)

If you need more details here is the 
All Plug-in Code:

https://github.com/jmillerdesign/Cipher-Behavior-for-CakePHP/blob/master/Model/Behavior/CipherBehavior.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the estimated answer is, source string length + `35%` (of source str length).

I did a test like this to find the answer:

```
$key = 'really long key hello world';

// Source String
$str = '';
for ($i = 1; $i <= 2000; $i++) {
    $str .=  'x';
}
$slength = strlen($str);
echo 'source str length = '. $slength."<br>";
$encrypted = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $str, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));

$elength = strlen($encrypted);
echo 'encrypted str length = '. $elength."<br>";

echo 'diff = '. (($elength - $slength)/$slength) * 100 .'%';
```

---

Outputs:

```
source str length = 2000
encrypted str length = 2688
diff = 34.4%


source str length = 20000
encrypted str length = 26668
diff = 33.34%
```

---

Instead of using a fixed `varchar`, why don't you use the field type `text`?

Comment: Ofcourse the type of TEXT! I don't know why didn't I think of it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use CakePHP's Security::encrypt() method instead, as it is using Rijndael-256 out of the box. Rijndael ciphers are a variable length depending on the key used, so a VarChar will not work. The ciphertext is binary data and there's no need to encode it, so you would use a BLOB field instead.